# Expanding a table with multiline cells into a full table

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a table with cells that contain data in multiple lines and would like to split those into individual cells while maintaining the data's relationship with its adjacent data in the original format.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvFIy8jHT9jmJCkOg9kiPJFIsX8-lajGOKG6eaJmwsU/edit#gid=2101860964

How can this be done using a formula? (preferably just a single arrayformula, that is not limited by the size of the array or 50k character counts)

All values are randomly generated and hold no meaning. Assume to be non-unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(E:E, CHAR(10)))<>"", 
 "♦"&A:A&" ♠"&B:B&" ♠"&C:C&" ♠"&D:D&" ♠"&SPLIT(E:E, CHAR(10)), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠"))
```

[image: 0]